# jQuery Flot - Rounding the x-axis values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, flot

Struggling a bit here, because if I've understood the docs correctly (though I'll admit is probably not the case!), this should be working.

I'm using a Coldfusion CFC to grab data and return it in JSon format. Data is returned as 2 numeric values, i.e 6 & 1, 3 & 2 and so on.  The 'x-axis' value is a day, i.e day 1, day 2 etc.

Currently, the x-axis is displaying it as 2.5, 5, 7.5 etc.  I need this to change so its displayed as it's returned - i.e 1,2,3 etc.

This is the JS I have right now, which executes without error, but doesn't display the chart as intended...

```
$(function() {
$.getJSON("/com/stats.cfc?method=getPageViews&returnformat=json", {}, function(data) {
 $.plot($("#chart"), [ data ],
    {
        lines:{show:true},
        points:{show:true},
        tickSize:1, 
        tickDecimals:0
    })

})
});
```

Pointers much appreciated!

Comment: Could you please give an example of numbers and how they are displayed in Coldfusion, in JSON, in the final result and how you want them to be display for any of the steps where it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @zeebonk.  I've just figured out the issue and posted the correct syntax I was missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Purely by luck, I've figured out the correct syntax.  For the benefit of anyone search for this, here's the updated working code;

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("/com/stats.cfc?method=getPageViews&returnformat=json", {}, function(data) {
        $.plot($("#chart"), [ data ],
        {
            lines:{show:true},
            points:{show:true},
            xaxis: 
                {
                    tickSize:1, 
                    tickDecimals:0
                }
        })

    })
});
```